# ASP.NET 4.0 Routing and Default.aspx (How write A Handler? Is It Necessary Or Not)

Tags: c#, url-routing, asp.net-4.0

i want to route Default.aspx to another URL when page starts.
my global.asax is like this :

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute(
        "Default",                                                          // Route name
        "My Site",                                                          // URL with parameters
        "~/Default.aspx"                                                    // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

should i write a handler for my purpose?
(i found some samples for .net 3.5 and MVC but what about .net 4 web forms)
if yes how can i write it?

**EDIT:**
what this line exactly do?

```
    routes.Add("Default", new Route(string.Empty, new RouteHandler("~/Default.aspx")));
```

i am using web forms -> Not MVC

thanks in advace

Comment: Do you simply want to reset the starting page of the site?

Comment: hi Andre, what is that your mean about reset? i just want to route "Default.aspx" To "My Site" when page starts.  mean when a user type "www.domain.com/Default.aspx" he/she will see "www.domain.com/My Site" in his/her browser.

Comment: i do n't know doing this is useful for SEO or not! i want do this job for all my pages.

Comment: Hi MoonLight, so it's not simply a start page setting, it's rather a redirect. I'm not sure if you are able to achieve that with a routing table, but I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Just fyi, routing is not a redirect.  It essentially creates an abstraction between a url and the handler which serves the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a specific example of how to deal with routing on asp.net 4.0 web forms (it's just under the mvc part).

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

The way you are approaching it is fine.  You do have an error in the second parameter of your route.  Well perhaps not an error, I dislike spaces in urls as they are actually the encoded spaces.  Check out the guide.

Just noticed your edit.
Adding the route essentially creates a mapping between a url or url pattern (which you have as string.Empty which is a problem) and a handler which serves the request(You specify RouteHandler which I don't believe actually exists?).  .net Provides a PageRouteHandler which allows you to specify which page responds to your request and deal with a couple other details like security defined on the physical structure of your site.  Internally, MapPageRoute is simply calling routes.Add but using the PageRouteHandler.